# Are the following vector spaces?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

I need to tell if a given set is a vector space. Let me know if my reasoning is correct please.

1) S = {(4t,-7t, 6t) | t is a real number}

I checked if it has the zero vector= YES

I check if it is closed under scalar multiplication : 
     c4t, c(-7t), c6t... Then I would say NOT closed since they are not of the original form 2t,-3t,7t when t is not 1.
So not a vector space.

For my next set

2) The set of all functions whose second derivative equals its third derivative

So lets say I have a function f(x), then this says f''(x)=f'''(x)

So, I immediately thought of $e^x$, which follows that condition. But, $e^x$ never contains the zero vector so I can say it is not a vector space.

Please let me know if my work makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference    use this to type latex commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $S$ is a vector space. Keep in mind that the product of two real numbers $t*c$ another real number: $(4 ct, ~-7ct, ~6 ct) = (4 \tau, ~-7\tau , ~6 \tau)$ where $\tau= tc$ is a real number. Closed under addition similarly.
2. This set of functions is also a vector space. You're right that $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$ is in it, but so is $(kf)(x) = k \mathrm{e}^x$ *including when* $k=0$. Other functions in this space might include things like constants and linear functions--writing them all down will get tiresome quickly! Instead, let's work on a symbolic level.

Let $f(x)$ be such that $f'' = f'''$ and let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $(\lambda f)''(x) = \lambda f''' (x) = (\lambda f)'''(x)$ due to the linearity of the derivative, so the function set is closed under scalar multiplication. Similarly, let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be such that $f''(x) = f'''(x)$ and $g''(x) = g'''(x)$. Then
$$ (f+g)''(x) = f''(x) + g''(x) = f'''(x) + g'''(x) = (f+g)'''(x)$$
so the set is also closed under addition.

Comment: This makes sense, but why do I have to check (kf)(x)=kex? If f(x)=$e^x$ is in it, and I say the zero vector isnt it it, then I found a function in S that isnt a VS.  EDIT: ohhhh I see, Im thinking about this wrong. The zero vector is in the set! Not every function has 0 in it so this makes sense. thank you

Comment: Exactly--a vector space must contain the zero vector (/function / matrix / ...), but we're allowed to have non-zero things as well. Usually the 0 element is easy enough to check on it's own, but you can also make sure that $0 \vec{v}$ is in the set for some $\vec{v} \in V$.